# Send reported properties to Azure IOT Central with IOS SDK

Tags: ios, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central

I'm struggling with the IOT Central SDK to send reported properties to my IOT Central but so far I haven't found any way to do it.

Have anyone managed to perform this very task? I have no problem sending properties or events / telemetries but I've been struggling with this for a while with no results.

Answer (score 0):

The [Device Twins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins) features are supported for devices with the MQTT or AMQP protocols to the Azure IoT Central (Azure IoT Hub).

For your requirement such as using a device in the iOS Application, I do recommend using the MQTT protocol directly to the Azure IoT Central (Azure IoT Hub) and some iOS MQTT client library, for example [MQTT-Client-Framework](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-client-library-encyclopedia-mqtt-client-framework/).

For test purposes of the features how to use the MQTT protocol directly, you can use any MQTT client tools such as MQTTBox, MQTT.fx, etc.

The following screen snippets show an example of using the MQTT protocol directly to the Azure IoT Central, where the MQTTBox client updated a device1 reported property (name *battery*):

[image]

[image]